# How to solve this "VALUE" error in excel with just one formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to extract this part => "1.3215809385571036" from following text and I use this formula {=MID(LEFT(A2;FIND(",";A2)-1);FIND("_";A2)+7;18)} for this.

**4_1100_ *1.3215809385571036*, X-Ray checking, Kino checking, GPS avto (kadr)**

But sometimes my text is looking like this and formula return "VALUE" error because "Find" function can not find "," and return error.

**1_1100_ *1.2152157818772644* Green gas. fekfmf eujffmmef. GPS chechking.**

How to solve this problem? How to write this formula for ....FIND(",";A2) and also FIND(" G";A2) with just one formula ?

Comment: Question: Are the number of characters always the same before this substring? Also, are the amount of characters of the substring itself always the same? In that case just use `=MID(A1,9,18)`. If not possible, please update your sample data to reflect different patterns.

Comment: the amount of characters of the substring are different in my data and so I want to use this formula for specific characters ("," and sometimes "G"). 1_1100_ 1.21557818772644 Green gas. fekfmf eujffmmef. GPS chechking.

Comment: Thanks, follow-up question: Is there actually a space before the substring or is that a typo?

Comment: {=MID(LEFT(A2;FIND(",";A2)-1);FIND("_";A2)+7;18)}  How to change this formula for  {....FIND(",";A2)-1....}   and also {...FIND("G";A2)-1...} ?

Comment: Yes, there is have a space before substring (1.2152157818772644)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=MID(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," ")," ","</s><s>'")&"</s></t>","//s[2]"),2,LEN(A1))
```

Or, stuff like:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," ")," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1)),2),FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))
```

---

However,for those lucky ones with access to `TEXTSPLIT()`, you can use:

```
=INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,{" ",","}),2)
```

Comment: Sir, learnt a great trick today from the formula of `FILTERXML()` you have shared, I found that additional apostrophe really made a difference, without it just returns the decimal part

Comment: I tried to use "TEXTSPLIT()" but it doesn't work on my excel. I think excel version is old.

Comment: In your second formula, I want to understand it, why are you using REPT(" ",LEN(A1)) ?

Comment: @Turan_Aghayev, it's an ms365 insiders feature for now. Either way, if the answer you posted yourself works you have given us false information in the comment section. Good stuff you solved your problem though. You seem to account for a substring of exactly 18 characters for starters. Something I asked before which you said can differ.

Comment: @Turan_Aghayev, the 2nd formula I replaced all spaces with a sequence of spaces that is equal to the length of the input. That means we can safely say that if we then use `MID()` appropriately in the resulting string we will get the '2nd word', your substring of interest in this case.

Comment: You are right. Actually, I write the formula like this =MID(LEFT(A2;FIND(",";SUBSTITUTE(A2;" ";",";2))-1);FIND("_";A2)+7;LEN(A1)) not 18. I now editing answer.

Comment: @Turan_Aghayev, if it works for you then great, but I have my reservations. For example, you'll get an error for your 2nd sample.

Comment: can you see my last answer please? how this happened ?

Comment: @Turan_Aghayev, you are using the answer section wrongly. Also, what is not working with the answers given by me and Mayukh?

Comment: I know it. I am new user on stackoverflow and can not know how to post anything in this platform exactly. My data is anonymous regarding with my workplace that's why I change data every time. I can't show you real data. what are you thinking about my last answer which I post two pictures ?

Comment: @Turan_Aghayev, you should instead comment and/or accept any of the given answers if it helpen you or not. They appear to work for the data you gave whereas yours doesn't.

Comment: Your answers are working but I try to use different formulas for my learning. It develops my excel skills.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this as well,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")," ",REPT(" ",100)),100,100))
```